# Benchmarking vCore Performance

Tags: debian, performance, virtual-machines, benchmark

A certain public cloud provider is phasing out its old small VM instances and replacing it with a new category of instances. While the old model lists "vCore 2.4 GHz" the new model features "performance can vary slightly over time" and lists no clock speed.

It would be convenient to have some benchmark which gives a rough estimate of the computational performance of the VM instances. Is there such?

The systems run Debian images.

Comment: I found an article in German language ([link](https://www.webhosterwissen.de/know-how/server/server-benchmark/)).

Comment: I spun up a couple of different instances and tried the sysbench benchmark from the article mentioned above. To my surprise I ended up with about 10s for each run, though the instances vary in CPU frequency (as can be seen in /proc/cpuinfo). Weird.

Comment: It gets weirder: Same instance, but ubuntu image instead of debian: here I measured 30s.